# How can i use LINQ with property

Tags: linq, lambda, linq-to-entities, linq-to-objects

Hi I have a array list if type class "DtContract".

```
ArrayList listOfContracts_;

foreach (DTContract contract in listOfContracts_)
{
    if (contract.Engine != DTIsland.EngineType.AMADEUS && contract.Engine !=DTIsland.EngineType.SABRE)
                    continue; 
}
```

I want to do it through LINQ.
I want to filter the Contract whose `EngineType == AMADEUS && EngineType == SABRE`. Please suggest how can i do it through Linq and get the result in List or in array list.

I am doing this to Optimize the code.

Please Help...

Comment: Do you want to optimize for speed or for readability? Because converting this `foreach` loop to a Linq query won't improve the speed.

Comment: @Elian :  So how can i improve it??  Please Suggest..

Comment: Your are missing the constructor call and `listOfContracts_.add(contract)` in your code.
What Elian ment is, that linq will internally perform the same, your currently do, and that there is nothing to optimize, from a performance perspective).

Comment: @Nappy: actually it just an example so i dont wright listOfContracts_.add(contract)

Answer (score 1):

```
var result = listOfContracts_.Where(contract=>contract.Engine != DTIsland.EngineType.AMADEUS && contract.Engine !=DTIsland.EngineType.SABRE).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

your foreach loop doen't do anything meaningful, what you are trying achieve?

If you want to use linq

```
listOfContracts_.OfType<DTContract>()
   .Where(contract => contract.Engine != DTIsland.EngineType.AMADEUS && 
                      contract.Engine != DTIsland.EngineType.SABRE);
```